# Get Rid of shaded background around ImageView

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I am trying to get rid of this slightly dark box around my image.

My app

[image: picture]

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/playButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/image_1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

The background is transparent and this box is appearing. The image itself has a transparent background (I made the image have a transparent background by using gimp2). Does anyone know why this box is appearing?

Comment: What if you remove the ImageView or hide it then what background color in place of it you see?

Comment: Holo green dark. Which is what it should be but it is not. Think it is because of what i did in gimp.

Comment: Just add visibility gone to ImageView and then check

Comment: That just got rid of the whole image.

Comment: The above was just to check the background color and not a solution